# Parse xml to dictionary or array of dictionaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, axios

I am getting text/xml from a soap service with axios. How do I convert it to something I can easily read the values from?

This is the axios part:

```
axios.post('https://something.net?WSDL',
        xmls,
    {headers:
    {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/xml',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        SOAPAction : ''}
    })
.then(response => {
    this.weather.single = response.data
})
```

and I am getting an xml string out of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><getCurrWeatherResponse xmlns="http://service"><getCurrWeatherReturn><currWindSpeed>31</currWindSpeed><currTemp>-4</currTemp><currWindDir>north</currWindDir></getCurrWeatherReturn></getCurrWeatherResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am going to have to work with arrays of those too

Comment: Which values would you like to read from the xml string in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xml2json` npm. This will convert XML to json

`npm install xml2json`

```
let xmlParser = require('xml2json');

axios.post('https://something.net?WSDL',
        xmls,
    {headers:
    {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/xml',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        SOAPAction : ''}
    })
.then(response => {
    this.weather.single = xmlParser.toJson(response.data)
})
```

Try this.

Here I got this response

```
{
 "soapenv:Envelope": {
  "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
  "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
  "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
  "soapenv:Body": {
   "getCurrWeatherResponse": {
    "xmlns": "http://service",
    "getCurrWeatherReturn": {
     "currWindSpeed": "31",
     "currTemp": "-4",
     "currWindDir": "north"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```